# their relationship after the incident were or was?

Tags: grammar

**What is the correct way to use was/were**

1. their relationship after the incident were?

---

2. their relationship after the incident was?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, "was" is used for singular objects, and “were” is used for plural objects.
In your sentence fragment 'their' > pronoun; 'relationship' is the object was/were refers to and is singular.

Their relationship after the incident **was**...

Additionally, 'Was' is used in the first person singular (I) and the third person singular (he, she, it).

'Were' is used in the second person singular and plural (you, your, yours) and first and third person plural (we, they).